# What is effective entity in guidewire and how we can create it?

Tags: guidewire, gosu

What is effective entity in guide wire and how we can create it. Please explain.

Comment: Effective entity?

Comment: one has to assume he means an effectiveDated entity.

Answer (score 4):

An *effdated* entity is an editable entity with additional effective date fields, meaning ***start*** and ***end*** dates. It is a member of an effective dated graph, rooted at an *effdatedbranch* entity.

To create an effdated entity, just select the type as effdated while creating a new entity from the editor.

Here are some inherited columns that effdated entities can have.

```
EffectiveDate - Date the entity instance becomes effective.
ExpirationDate - Date the entity instance expires or is no longer effective
SliceDate - The slice date is the current view, or slice, of the branch (and its entities) in effective time.
FixedID - Identifies a single object across effective date periods
```

Comment: Well explained.. Thanks